# Fabric Icon for twitter integration in eclipse juno not working after installation

Tags: eclipse, twitter, eclipse-juno, twitter-fabric

I am trying to open Fabric icon on the title bar but the Icon is Not working it just showing the show fabric on hover the icon .... help me 
   how to solve this problam

Install it from

help->install ->add->fabric, https://fabric.io/download/eclipse -> after successful adding no error

but still not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Do you see any message when hovering over the Fabric icon?

Comment: yes it is showing ""show fabric"" .

Comment: Did you install using the full .zip of Fabric? Do you have full permissions on your machine? If not, try installing the plugin after launching Eclipse in Admin mode.